# How to I find a case based on the ThreadID?

Tags: case

Case emails get generated with a threadid but there does not seem to be an easy way to find that actual case in Saleforce based on the threadid.  You cannot just do a search using the threadid for instance.  Any suggestions for how to do this?  It would be great if the threadid was listed as a field in the case so that it was searchable.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be a bit tricky but you may do it. After researching your situation I've come across to [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XvdHAAS). So we have the Thread Id formula. (*You may need to adjust this to get exact thread id and it is not guarenteed to work always.*)

1. You need to create a custom text field on Case object.
2. Create a workflow rule on Case.
3. Add a worklow field update for the custom field you created on case creation. After that you can add this formula to field update.

It will populate your newly created custom field with thread id and you'll be able to search it from global search.

**Note**: There is a little typo in formula. Correct version is this:

```
"ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" )& "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(Left(RIGHT(Id,10), 5), "0", "") & RIGHT(Id,5) & ":ref"
```

Comment: If the fifth character of an Id is 0, is it still included in the thread id?

Comment: Also I think it should be `SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(<id_value>, 6), "0", "")`. See for example: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008vOVIAY

Comment: In the orgs I've had to use this trick on sometimes I end up having to adjust the LEFT/RIGHT indexes by one. Really wish Salesforce exposed this on Case's directly and/or gave us a formula that doesn't change over time and/or is consistent in ALL orgs.